# Enrollment when configuring wso2 emm

Tags: email, configure, ubuntu-15.10, wso2-iot

I have a problem configuring the WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager when I want to add a new user. I add the user with his email address, except that the user does not receive the mail. In the logs I have the error: "The system can not infer the transport information from the mailto: ...". I configure the file axis2.xml with the Gmail SMTP and the email address of my user. But it's the only file I've changed in the mail configuration. Are there more configurations to perform?

Comment: please add more details and error log

Comment: This problem was resolved through a reboot. Now I receive the mail but without password and with this error message in the logs (wso2carbon.log) :                                                                                                 Error occurred while delivering the message, subject : 'You have neen invited to enroll your device in wso2 emm", to : .....                                      Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error creating mail message or sending it to the configured server.... Caused by javax.mail.authenticationFailetion

Comment: I would like to share you screenshots but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, it works, it was just a bug with a user. After having created a new one I have the password in the mail